# Wordpress not showing pages (showing another index.php)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site in a folder of another site :

```
www
--/ MyFirstSite
--/          --/  index.php
--/          --/  other.php

--/          --/  WordPress /  wp-config.php

--/          --/  WordPress /  etc
```

So the first page of my wordpress site is working perfectly, but when i go to another page for exemple :

```
http://   www.MyFirstSite   /   WordPressSite   /   anotherpage
```

There is a problem : it is showing me, the index.php of MyFirstSite

So i don't understand .. Please help me

I dont have a htaccess in wwww/MyFirstSite
And the htaccess of the wordpress :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WordPressSite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /WordPressSite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```